# Error incomprensible con HashMap

Tags: java, poo, class, map, hashmap

Tengo una aplicación que funciona correctamente hasta que creo en una clase un HashMap con el siguiente código:

```
public abstract class CuentaCorriente extends CuentaBancaria {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

HashMap <Integer, String> entidadesAutorizadas = new HashMap <String, String>();
entidadesAutorizadas.put("1", "Banco Santander");
entidadesAutorizadas.put("2", "La Caixa");
entidadesAutorizadas.put("3", "Banco Sabadell");
entidadesAutorizadas.put("4", "BBVA");
entidadesAutorizadas.put("5", "Bankia");
```

}

Cuando creo este HashMap, el programa rompe al compilar y además luego ya no me encuentra el método main de la clase principal. Algo super extraño, entonces, comento el HashMap creado y pulsado Shift + F11 vuelvo a reconstruir el proyecto. Me vuelve a funcionar, pero si vuelvo a intentar crear el HashMap de arriba, todo vuelve a pasar.

¿Sabéis por qué puede pasar esto?

Comment: No puedes acceder al objeto `entidadesAutorizadas` desde el cuerpo de la clase. Debes hacerlo en un método como el constructor.

Comment: `HashMap<Integer, String> = new HashMap<String, String>` .... <Integer, String> == <String, String>?? Has declarado el hashmap de un tipo y lo has instanciado diferente... Por mucho que sean genéricos, debes respetarlos. El tipado es tipado, sea como sea :)

Comment: Vale, tal vez haya copiado el código estando haciendo pruebas pero aunque ponga como lo decís (que en un principio lo tenía bien) sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @Lobos Vale, en un método main dices, no? o al menos en un método que luego sea llamado desde el método main?

Comment: Agrega la clase completa y la clase CuentaBancaria por favor. Comenta que error se muestra como salida al no poder compilar

Answer (score 0):

tu error esta aca:

```
HashMap <Integer, String> entidadesAutorizadas = new HashMap <String, String>();
```

estas declarando un hashmap de tipo key=Integer,Value=String y cuando lo inicializas colocas key=String,Value=String
La manera correcta es la siguiente:

```
HashMap <Integer, String> entidadesAutorizadas = new HashMap <Integer, String>();
```

Comment: Vale, tal vez haya copiado el código estando haciendo pruebas pero aunque ponga como lo decís (que en un principio lo tenía bien) sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: entidadesAutorizadas.put("1", "Banco Santander"); aca tienes la key como string entonces si el primer parametro como integer no servira tiene que ser :
entidadesAutorizadas.put(1, "Banco Santander");